# Is there are a sort method that would take multiple comparators and use them in case the sort order is same for a list of elements?

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I have a list of Offers to be given out. Each offer has a score, last date and offer value  associated with it. I want these offers to be sorted on offer Score.
This was simple to do using 
Collections.sort(..).

Now, if the offers have same score, i want to sort on last date.
If the last dates is also same, I want to sort on Offer value.

I have written datesComparator and ValueComparator for this.

Then I did the following which is quite expensive

1. Sort Offers based on offerScore.--> List
2. Take out offers with same score from Step 1.--> List
3. Sort Offers from Step 2 based on last Date and or Offer Value. --> List
4. Add back List from Step 3 to List in 
   Step 1.--> List
5. For Step 4 , use sort on offer score again, since sort method doesn't change the order of offers with same score.

I was wondering if there's a simpler method that would take up multiple comparators and then the sort would take up next comparator in case the result of first comparator is same for consecutive offers!!

Comment: `Comparator.thenComparing` (and variants).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`Comparator.thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.Comparator)).

> Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with another comparator. If this `Comparator` considers two elements equal, i.e. `compare(a, b) == 0`, `other` is used to determine the order.

```
default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<? super T> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable) (c1, c2) -> {
        int res = compare(c1, c2);
        return (res != 0) ? res : other.compare(c1, c2);
    };
}
```

For instance,

```
Comparator<Offer> comparator = 
    Comparator.comparingInt(Offer::getOfferScore)
              .thenComparing(Offer::getLastDate)
              .thenComparingInt(Offer::getOfferScore);
```

(assuming these methods exist)

### UPDATE

```
Comparator<Offer> comparator =
// OfferScore -> DESC
Comparator.comparingInt(Offer::getOfferScore).reversed()
// Dates -> ASC
.thenComparing(Offer::getLastDate)                    
// Value -> DESC   
.thenComparing(Comparator.comparingInt(Offer::getOfferScore).reversed());
```

Comment: in the above piece of code, what if I want to change the sort order for one of the comparator, say lastDate.
How can I do that?

Comment: `Collections.sort(offers, Comparator.comparingInt(Offer :: getOfferScore).thenComparing(this::compareLastDate).thenComparing(this::compareValue).reversed());`   
I want to sort in below order :
OfferScore -> DESC
Dates -> ASC
Value -> DESC

Comment: @the_way updated according to my original answer (because I don't know what your `this::compareLastDate` and `this::compareValue` are). Anyways, you should get the idea.

Comment: Tobliko
`Collections.sort(
            programs,
            Comparator
                .comparingInt((ProgramSortCriteria::getProgramScore)).reversed()
                    .thenComparing(ProgramSortCriteria::getProgramShutOffDate)
                        .thenComparing(ProgramSortCriteria::getSavingsValue).reversed()
        );`

This is my current code.

This line
`thenComparing(ProgramSortCriteria::getSavingsValue).reversed()`
is reversing the order of complete list of offers.

How to avoid this?

Comment: @the_way it should be `.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(ProgramSortCriteria::getSavingsValue).reversed());` or a narrower version of `comparingXXX` depending of the type of `getSavingsValue`

Comment: I did this 
`public int offerScoreForSort() {
        return -1 * OfferScore;
    }`

Same for value.

Comment: @the_way you don't need a separate method for such things. You could write a lambda  `Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i.getSavingsValue() * -1)`

Answer (score 2):

The `java.util.Comparator` interface has all methods you need to chain comparisons together. So your code may look something like this:

```
        List<Offer> offers = getOffers();
        offers.sort(Comparator
                .comparing(Offer::getOfferScore)
                .thenComparing(Offer::getOfferValue)
                .thenComparing(Offer::getLastDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing are not represented by multiple `Comparator<Offer>`s, because one single `Comparator<Offer>` is enough to represent that logic. Remember that `Comparator<T>` simply represents *a way* to compare two objects. It can be any way, however complicated it may be. This is also why `Collections.sort` does not provide methods that takes multiple `Comparator<T>`s.

You can combine multiple `Comparator<T>`s into a single `Comparator<T>` (with more complicated logic) using [`Comparator.thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) (and its primitive counterparts) to achieve what you want:

```
Comparator<Offer> complicatedComparator = 
    Comparator.comparing(Offer::getOfferScore)
        .thenComparing(Offer::getLastDate)
        .thenComparing(Offer::getOfferValue);
```